# Removing every 4th, 5th and 6th element in a Python list

Tags: python, list

I'd like to remove every 4th to 6th elements from a list.
The list is of permutations of 4 numbers, it is as follows:

```
A = map(list, permutations([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

These are the first 12 elements from the output of `A[0:12]`, and the other list is the desired output, with the 4th-to-6th elements removed from this bit of the overall list.

```
 [[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 4, 3],
 [1, 3, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 4, 2],
 [1, 4, 2, 3],
 [1, 4, 3, 2],
 [2, 1, 3, 4],
 [2, 1, 4, 3],
 [2, 3, 1, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 1],
 [2, 4, 1, 3],
 [2, 4, 3, 1]],
```

After removal, the list should be:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 4, 3],
 [1, 3, 2, 4],

 [2, 1, 3, 4],
 [2, 1, 4, 3],
 [2, 3, 1, 4]],
```

But my code outputs an error.

Comment: So every 3rd-6th or 4th-6th? Can you edit your question and put there expected result?

Comment: What is “every 4th-6th”? Please show the effect on a sample list.

Comment: Your sample data is a list of lists of length 4 for each sublist, what do you mean with 3rd-6th element?

Comment: And  it doesn't make sense to remove a randomly chosen permutation, either

Comment: So for every 12 elements, you want to remove elements 4–6?

Comment: I guess more like for every 6 elements, remove the last 3. Like if A[0:6], remove the last 3 elements.

Comment: Okay. This can’t be done by taking or deleting a slice, like you were trying with `del A[::3:7]`. With that information in mind, try writing a function that takes an index and returns `True` if the index should be included, `False` if it should be removed. `f(0) == f(1) == f(2) == f(6) == f(7) == f(8) == True`, `f(3) == f(4) == f(5) == f(9) == f(10) == f(11) == False`.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a go. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "But it outputs an error". Please `edit `to include the exact error message, as per SO guidelines. Please read [how to ask](https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Also, what did you try? Please include your coding attempt as per SO guidelines (see link above). What is the code that produced the error you allude to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
B=A[:4]
B.extend(A[7:])
```

should do the trick.

Comment: `list.extend` doesn’t return a value.

Comment: Or rather, it returns `None`

Comment: @Ry- Happy now?

Comment: No, now this will do nothing at all. (Well, it’ll be a syntax error, but after fixing that, nothing.)

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it's better to include an explanation on how your code addresses the OP's issue. This way, future visitors can learn from your post, & apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, complete answers reinforce this idea, and are more likely to be upvoted. These features, plus the requirement that all posts be self-contained, are some strengths of SO as a platform that differentiates us from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score -2):

TITLE CURRENT READS "removing every **3rd**-6th element in a list - pythoN" yet question current reads "I'd like to remove every **4th**-6th elements out of a list.", but iether way, this is done the same in every programming language, you have to lop through it, starting from the end, and remove it if the index % 3 == 0, for example, for pseudo-code

```
variable someList = []
for(variable index = someList.length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    if(index % 3 == 0) delete someList[index]
```

adapt it accordingly to any programming language, essentially

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Psuedo code is not appropriate for most Answers on SO. The programming language is listed, and Answers are expected to include exact code necessary to solve the OP's question. Anything that is not a full, definitive, self-contained compete answer (including exact code, if relevant), is more appropriately left as a Comment to the OP's question. Please 'edit' to replace any psuedo code and references with actual code in the language specified. Note: spelling, grammar, & punctuation are *important*. Refer to [help](https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for info.

Comment: @SherylHohman hey there seems to be some kind of error here, whenever I try to actually reply to you, my comments get deleted, I wonder how that could be? anyways, as ai was saying, for about the 1000th time, pseudo-code is an essential way to answer a question, since if just the plain code was given, the one asking would just copy and paste it without understanding what it means, but pseudo-code gives them the general idea of the matter, so that they can learn to think for themselves. Kapeesh? Does it say anything against that in the terms of service?

Comment: This is the first message I've seen, so if your accusation is true, I would assume moderators have determined your comments were not useful/appropriate. Please review [Help Documentation](https://StackOverflow.com/help). The SO platform designed Answers to provide definitive answers, not ideas for answers. Suggestions are fine as Comments, but not as Answers. eg Homework Qs encourage HINTS to be left in comments. Answers can *include* psuedo code *in addition* to actual code for the language tagged. But that would rarely be useful. (How to Answer)[https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-answer]

Comment: @SherylHohman ok, in the link you sent me, it doesn't mention anything about pseudo-code or no pseduo-code, so may I ask where you are getting that information from exactly?

Comment: Please read all the top posts from each category in the Help section. This is the prevailing guideline. The principle of SO is to provide definitive, exact coded Answers, with explanations, wherever possible. You can include pseudo code if you want (though not generally advised), but Answers are required to be definitive & complete, and coded in the language tagged, with very few exceptions that would be specific & unique to the Question asked. Other StackExchange sites, and other platforms may be fine with pseudo-code only Answers. Incomplete solutions are an encouraged use of Comments on SO.